# What it's the best to store user data with react during a session?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm working on a react application as a front and as the back python, Django and rest.
I'll do the front part in a few days, but a question spawn: how can I manage all my apps for the user with an account and the other (without the account)?

I look a few options but I don't really know which one is better:

- local storage
- context API
- cookies

For example if the user is connected and wants to see him own profile page, he could without fetch in the code cause it's just a few information like name, email, ...
I don't know if it's enough to clear but hopefully enough to get some suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies are mainly for reading server-side, whereas local storage can only be read by the client-side. 
An other point is saving data, a big technical difference is the size of data you can store, localStorage give you more space.

Context API you'll use it eather you work with cookies or localStorage

Comment: Ok so localStorage it's the best way for the client-side. What you mean but "you'll use it eather you work with cookies or localStorage" like I must use it I can't make an app without ?

Comment: You can use ContextAPI if you work with Hooks to access to data in an other child (sub child) component. and it's not mandatory in a react app (working with classes)

Comment: Just the last question! I must do it now or i can setup the localStorage with context API later after every work ?

Comment: It's recommanded to setup your binding when you start your project if you have the whole view. it depends also on you your use case :D

Answer (score 0):

You can call the API for fetching information the first time the user logs in, and then you could store the information on the app state for the whole session. If you want to store information between sessions localstorage works just fine, is easy to access. However, you'll have to check if this information exists when the user logs in.

Comment: Ok so you suggest me to use the localstorage so ? because I would like to access this data between every component, even if they are not children or parents. I know i can do it with localstorage but don't know if it's the best way.

Comment: Caching is also an option.

Answer (score 0):

**Context API** can help you to access the stored data easily by using **useContext** react hook API in other child components and manage them by React, but **localStorage** is a way to **persists** Context API **changes** with localStorage to get them back after every page reloads(prevent losing data in page refresh). But cookies have a maximum length(I don't know how much is it) which isn't the best way because it has security issues and a use-case of cookies is using them on the server-side by the backend.

Comment: Ok so you all me recommended to use localStorage right ? with context API so with that I ll have something safe and clean. The most important I ll have access to the data every right ? so I'll try it !